# PHP setcookie in cURL request

Tags: php, curl

I have a page that sets 3rd party cookie using PHP. When I access that page directly setcookie works fine, but when I use cURL to get information from that page setcookie doesn't work.

Is there any way to set a cookie when that page is requested using cURL?

Answer (score 0):

```
$myValue = curl_init('yourUrl');
curl_setopt($myValue, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// get headers too with this line
curl_setopt($myValue, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($myValue);
// get cookie
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $value);

parse_str($value[1], $cookies);
var_dump($cookies);
```

may be it help you

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if I get anything from it.

Comment: So I'm getting the cookie back, how do I set it?

Comment: I need to set cookie with the domain of the requested page, not with the domain that does cURL request.

Comment: Are you  looking for $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("testCokice", $testValue, 0, '/', ".example.com");
```

By this example  you can set Cookie in PHP form domain